# JavaScript File Api and Encodings with Excel Spreadsheet uploads

Tags: javascript, file-upload, file-io, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to figure out how to detect file encoding before the file actually gets uploaded. I basically have a multipart form with a file type input and just want to do a rudimentary check whether a xlsx file is UTF-8 compliant (more or less) before the upload operation kicks off.

Trying to lessing the load on the server side which also does the validation but much more thoroughly... well, as thorough as you can be in Python 2+

Any ideas? Just rough code outlines or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. I know nothing of the JS file API

Comment: I see some people using charCodeAt to check the encoding but it seems messy

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#enctype

Comment: charCodeAt is technically incorrect for quite a few reasons, including the fact that it isn't actually UTF-8